# How to autofocus Android camera automatically?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to autofocus Android camera as soon as camera holds still. Im looking for tutorials or samples how to do it or at least small sample that shows what classes I can use to hook on such events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Camera AutoFocus on Demand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878042/android-camera-autofocus-on-demand)

Answer (score 122):

For me this worked a treat:

```
//set camera to continually auto-focus
Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters();
//*EDIT*//params.setFocusMode("continuous-picture");
//It is better to use defined constraints as opposed to String, thanks to AbdelHady
params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
c.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: Min SDK 14 for this. Is there a way for Min SDK < 14 ?

Comment: Where does this code snippet go? I am working with a heavy Unity3D app (C#) that scans a serial-number, but it seems that the Android device's camera does not auto-focus, therefore the scanning (and character recognition) is really bad. Where should I put this code?

Comment: `Camera.Parameters` is deprecated in SDK 21 and above.

Comment: You should check whether the device supports the focus mode as it is done in dcoz' answer to prevent a RuntimeException in `setParameters()`

Answer (score 63):

Try to use `Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO` or `Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`.
See below:

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
if (params.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(
    Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
  params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
}
camera.setParameters(params);
```

It's important to test whether the phone is supporting your chosen mode before attempting to use it, otherwise `setParameters()` will throw a runtime exception.
(Edit code now working properly)

Comment: works to autofocus camera, but once I start recording it looses focus again

Comment: Nevermind, I was opening the cam again so it lost the first permissions.

Comment: I just did some testing.  You might want to use `Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` instead if you want to do text/barcode recognition or focusing on a piece of paper.

Comment: whats your point here? Did you get better results in the stream with continuous picture? Normally the recommended mode for a stream is continuous video

Answer (score 19):

Following code works for me.

Setting autofocus (preview class):

```
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
//some more settings
camera.setParameters(params);
```

Call camera for shot a picture in case that autofocus is ready (activity class):

```
public void butClick(View v){
    preview.camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            if(success){
                camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Get picture (activity class):

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        //do something
    }
};
```

Comment: answer of "Jens van de Mötter" is better than others,because the camera is auto focus only when we are going to capture.so i think it saves bit energy.

Comment: Why does setting the autofocus go in preview class? Seems to me like activity class would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you should [continuous autofocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO) as is discussed here.

There is a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878042/android-camera-autofocus-on-demand) that you can reference.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for preview callback:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
if (parameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(
        Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
}
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try code:

```
ShutterCallback _pfnShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    PictureCallback _pfnRawPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    private AutoFocusCallback _pfnAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera.autoFocus(null);
            camera.takePicture(_pfnShutterCallback, _pfnRawPictureCallback,
                    mPicture);

        }
    };
    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            new SavePhotoTask().execute(data);
            camera.startPreview();

        }
    };
class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {
// Process save file image
}
```

call capture : `mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);`

You can refer at:
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/start-camera-auto-focusing-autofocus.html