# How to auto focus custom camera without touch on screen when starting preview?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am stuck on the camera preview. I used custom camera preview. but there is a problem in this preview. Camera is going blur in initial stage and when touch on screen it will be focused. but I want to camera preview is focusing from starting the preview. I have searched many question but did not get any resolving answer related this. I am beginner in android so please help me if anyone knows the answer of this question.

Comment: Check this page https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback . This should help you

Comment: I have already checked this but my case is different I want to focusing on start camera before taking picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623944/how-to-autofocus-android-camera-automatically)

But it's possible maybe your phone is focusing on something else... since its autofocus. When you tap on the screen, it's like telling your phone to focus on that particular object.