# Android auto focus when continuous auto focus modes are not supported

Tags: android, android-camera, autofocus

I have a camera in my app and I want to make it auto focus continuously in the same way that the phone's camera does it. I found the modes `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO` and `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`, but they are not supported by some of the HTC Gingerbread phones I'm testing on.

This is what I'm doing to determine whether I can use these modes:

```
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<String> supportedFocusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH &&
            supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        }
        else if (supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
        }
        else if (supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
            // auto focus on request only
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        }
```

Running on several different Gingerbread HTC phones I don't get the continuous modes back, but I get "auto". This lets me auto focus on demand (when I call `mCamera.autoFocus(null)`, but the camera will not refocus if the user moves the camera.

I cannot set the focus mode to anything the camera does not support, and if I do it shows up blank.

One solution that I tried is to call `mCamera.autoFocus(null)` on a timer. This causes the camera to refocus continuously, even if it is already in focus.

Is there a way to implement a continuous auto focus experience on these phones? When I look at HTCs camera app on these phones it does have continuous auto focus - as you move around the camera refocuses and does not keep refocusing once the picture is in focus.

Comment: After a lot more hours spent on this, I'm investigating the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10555471/1481500)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a requirement to support a very wide range of phones. My solution in the end was to handle each case differently.

For the scenario of phones without continuous auto-focus support I implemented a utility to listen to the accelerometer using `SensorManager` and trigger `mCamera.autoFocus(...)` whenever the user moves the camera.

There were also some older tablets that only supported fixed focus (who would use such a thing!), in that case the picture needed to be taken immediately - not on the focus callback.

For most modern phones the code snippet above was fine to use `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`.

Comment: Hi [kos](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1481500/kos), I'm having a similar use-case to achieve. Can you please provide more detail about this utility of yours?

Comment: @kos, could you, please, explain how you define whether a device supports continuous auto-focus feature ?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar pb on my samsung S4 and I solved it with:

```
camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.autoFocus(null);
```

<sup>This is suggest in the Google doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html).</sup>

To make the camera parameters take effect, your application has to call `setParameters(Camera.Parameters)`.