# How display auto focus when preview camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

My code set auto focus when capture Image:

```
ShutterCallback _pfnShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onShutter() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };

        PictureCallback _pfnRawPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
```

// Auto focus call back

```
        private AutoFocusCallback _pfnAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camera.autoFocus(null);
                camera.takePicture(_pfnShutterCallback, _pfnRawPictureCallback,
                        mPicture);

            }
        };
```

//Start capture  Picture Call back  and save image...

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            new SavePhotoTask().execute(data);
            camera.startPreview();

        }
    };
    public void autoFocus(AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback) {
            if (Utilities.hasFeatureAutoFocus(E028.this)) {
                mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
                mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
            }
            else
            {
                playSound();
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        }
```

Call capture image: `autoFocus(_pfnAutoFocusCallback )`

I use code preview but don't display frame:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE))
            {
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            }
```

How start auto focus when preview camera the same image before capture?
[image]

Comment: Do you want to capture only the image inside the frame? You highlighted with a red rectangle, so do you want final image should be only the area which is inside the frame?

Comment: i want display auto focus when preview camera. Image demo is display of standard camera. I want my app display the same.

Comment: Make a custom view and add it the FrameLayout in your xml.

Comment: Do you know what is auto focus when preview camera?

Answer (score 9):

[Continuous auto focus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO) seems to be the hot answer.

[link 1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623944/how-to-autofocus-android-camera-automatically)
[link 2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878042/android-camera-autofocus-on-demand)

The following snippet may work, if not, please reference the above links:

```
//set camera to continually auto-focus
Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters();
if (params.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
} else {
    //Choose another supported mode
}
c.setParameters(params);
```